# Reinitialize a layout based on a config file

Tags: android

I have a Menu Activity and a Settings Activity. The Settings Activity is started from the Menu Activity so it always comes directly after the Menu Activity in the stack trace.

My Menu Activity has severel buttons, one for each function of the app. all of these functions can be enabled and disabled using the Settings Activity. Those configurations are saved in Preferences.

If a function is disabled it should not be available as a button in the Menu Screen.

So... the problem: I need to reload the whole Menu Activity after the user changed the configuration file using the Settings Activity otherwise i always have to restart the app until the changes are taking effect.

So how can i remove / add buttons from/to a layout of the menu activity when a certain button in the settings activity is clicked?

```
/**
 * 
 */
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    this.layoutMenu = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout);
    this.circularImageView = (CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_imageview_profile);
    this.circularImageView.setImageDrawable(Images.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getActivity(), Paths.IMAGE_PROFILE));
    this.textViewValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_textview_measure_value);
    this.textViewDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_textview_measure_date);
    this.textViewUnit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_textview_measure_unit);

    this.buttonProfile = new ImageButton(this.getActivity());
    this.buttonProfile.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.buttonProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile);
    this.buttonProfile.setBackground(null);

    this.buttonContacts = new ImageButton(this.getActivity());
    this.buttonContacts.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.buttonContacts.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_message);
    this.buttonContacts.setBackground(null);

    this.buttonCalc = new ImageButton(this.getActivity());
    this.buttonCalc.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.buttonCalc.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_calculator);
    this.buttonCalc.setBackground(null);

    this.buttonSettings = new ImageButton(this.getActivity());
    this.buttonSettings.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.buttonSettings.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_settings);
    this.buttonSettings.setBackground(null);

    String email = this.getEmail();
    Map<String, Boolean> config = this.sessionConfigPreferences.getConfigDetails(email);

    List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    views.add(this.buttonProfile);

    if(config.get(Globals.CONFIG_CONTACTS)) {
        views.add(this.buttonContacts);
    }

    if(config.get(Globals.CONFIG_CALC)) {
        views.add(this.buttonCalc);
    }

    views.add(this.buttonSettings);

    this.circleView = new CircularLayout(this.getActivity(), this, views);

    this.layoutMenu.addView(this.circleView);
}
```

And my CircularLayout:

```
public class CircularLayout extends DragableButtonsLayout {
    private List<View> menuButtons = null;
    private ImageView imageViewCenter = null;
    private ImageButton imageButtonCenter = null;
    private int radius = -1;
    private double step = -1;
    private double angle = -1;
    private static final int CENTER_ID = 111;

    public CircularLayout(Context context, DragCallback dragCallback, List<View> menuButtons) {
        super(context);

        this.dragCallback = dragCallback;
        this.menuButtons = menuButtons;
        this.radius = Sizes.getOptimalCenterRadius(context);
        this.step = (2 * Math.PI) / menuButtons.size();

        this.initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Sizes.getOptimalMenuHeight(this.getContext()));
        layoutParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutCenter = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
        relativeLayoutCenter.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsCenter);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsImageViewCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParamsImageViewCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        this.imageViewCenter = new ImageView(this.getContext());
        this.imageViewCenter.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImageViewCenter);
        this.imageViewCenter.setImageDrawable(Images.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getContext(), Paths.IMAGE_BACKGROUND_POWER));
        this.imageViewCenter.setBackground(null);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsImageButtonCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParamsImageButtonCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        this.imageButtonCenter = new ImageButton(this.getContext());
        this.imageButtonCenter.setId(CENTER_ID);
        this.imageButtonCenter.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImageButtonCenter);
        this.imageButtonCenter.setImageDrawable(Images.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getContext(), Paths.IMAGE_POWER));
        this.imageButtonCenter.setBackground(null);
        this.imageButtonCenter.setOnDragListener(new DropTargetOnDragListener());

        relativeLayoutCenter.addView(this.imageViewCenter);
        relativeLayoutCenter.addView(this.imageButtonCenter);
        relativeLayoutCenter.setOnDragListener(new MenuButtonOnDragListener());

        for(View view : this.menuButtons) {
            relativeLayoutCenter.addView(this.placeView(view));
        }

        this.addView(relativeLayoutCenter);
    }

    private View placeView(View view) {
        view.measure(0, 0);

        this.imageButtonCenter.measure(0, 0);

        int x = (int)((view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2) + this.radius * Math.cos(this.angle));
        int y = (int)((view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2) + this.radius * Math.sin(this.angle));

        this.angle += this.step;

        int deltaX = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int deltaY = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        int deltaImageX = this.imageButtonCenter.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int deltaImageY = this.imageButtonCenter.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        int xToDraw = ((x - deltaX) - deltaImageX);
        int yToDraw = ((y - deltaY) - deltaImageY);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParams.setMargins(xToDraw, 0, 0, yToDraw);

        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you building your GUI? If you are building it dynamically at run-time it will be easy just to add or not any button or control.

Comment: I added the relevant code. i already tried to just re initalize the view but i couldnt remove the views from the layout before i add the new views.

Comment: did you try "removeAllViews()" on the top layout?

Comment: yes. but it did not remove the views from the cild layouts (i really have no idea how this mechanism is working) but after the re initialization the views of the niew initialization are just overlayout the old views.

Comment: You have to go all the way here. When creating a dynamic layout you have to create all of the controls ex: Button myButton = new Button(this);
In this way you don't need to worry about grandchildren :)